Get column width of an excel speadsheet with a Perl module on a Linux system
While I'm able to create a XLSX file with Perl module Excel::Writer::XLSX and set a column's width, I can't find a way to get the width of a column in a spreadsheet of a XLSX file. I've tried Spreadsheet::ParseXLSX/Spreadsheet::ParseExcel (can't find a method to get the column width) and Spreadsheet::Read ($sheet->{col_width}[$col_index] returned empty value). Anyone has any info? Thanks.

According to the documentation,
Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::Worksheet has a get_col_widths method that should return the column widths.
You need to go through a workbook, not directly from a sheet.
